# Getting NSM Live Look PHP errors, even after uninstalling

Tags: error, php, plugin

I've had issues and PHP errors with NSM Live Look. It's been uninstalled and I thought it was fine, but the client has just informed me that when they try to post or edit an item from just one specific Channel, they are getting errors.

To confirm, if they try posting or editing an item from any other Channel this error does not appear.

These errors look like:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined index: nsm_live_look__preview
>   Filename: content/publish.php
>   Line Number: 145
>   " id="hold_field_
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined index: nsm_live_look__preview
>   Filename: content/publish.php
>   Line Number: 145
>   " style="width: 100%; display: none;">
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined index: nsm_live_look__preview
>   Filename: content/publish.php
>   Line Number: 151
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined index: nsm_live_look__preview
>   Filename: content/publish.php
>   Line Number: 152

As I said, I've already uninstalled the this plugin, plus I've checked the database and cannot even see an entry for *nsm_live_look*.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used NSM Live Look, but the nature of the error seems to indicate the channel's live look template is not set in the configuration.

That said, the severity of the errors above are mere 'Notices' and should probably be turned off on live production environments. You can disable error output display from:

Admin → System Administration → Output & Debugging → Debug Preference → **None**

Comment: Thanks. It's annoying how I can't get the error to go though. All reference to this plugin as been removed, well from what I can see anyway.